# Serve application via tomcat/ amazon ec2 cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat

I have access to an amazon machine ec2.XXXXXX.XXX . I have setup hudson CI tool on this machine and now I would like this to be served to people in my org. This is my first attempt and really new to this . Can someone please guide me on the points below:

1> I can access tomcat/hudson with local host on the port number i provided but how to make it available to the rest of the org
2> I do not require domain registration for ec2 and would like to access my application as 
ec2.xx.xx.xx/hudson. How can i do this 
3> Also permit users only with a username and password to access this site like from .htaccess in apache 
4>I want tomacat to serve as http server as well and  what connector settings should i modify.

I looked at the docs but may be missing some basic points. Can some guide in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some combination of the following:

- If Tomcat is to be the web server, then you should allow its HTTP connector port in the security group for that EC2 instance so that it can be accessed from outside.  You cannot and should not use port 80 as only root can launch processes on ports under 1000 and it is not advisable to run Java as root due to security and other issues.
- Hudson's built-in user management should be enough.

Comment: Yes, it was related to opening port but I had to open port 80 itself.Anyways, I need to check for other than this port. Thanks for your response.